# How do I test a function that sends a request in browser that requires authentication?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, session, mocha.js, chai

I'm in the process of writing unit tests in Mocha and Chai, and I'm trying to figure out how to test a function that that uses the `fetch` API to send a request that requires a session to access. This function is an ES6 method that returns a `thenable` object.

```
_auth(record) {
    var authMetadata = this._getAuthMetadata(record);
    var authUrl = `/${this._getPortal(window.location.pathname)}/tlist_child_auth.html?${this._encodeUri(authMetadata)}`;
    if (getPortal() !== 'guardian') {
      authUrl += `&frn=${this.coreTableNumber}${this.foreignKey}`;
    }
    return fetch(authUrl, {
      credentials: 'include'
    }).then(function(rawData) {
      return rawData.text();
    });
  }
```

`tlist_child_auth.html` is the page that requires session authorization to access. Is there any easy way to do this, or should I seek to "invent the wheel"?

Comment: Unsure in this context, but in other unit testing I would be using a mock of `fetch` (otherwise you're testing _that_ function and everything upstream of it too, including the website by the sounds of things), that when called returns something known, so that you can make sure you get back the data you think you should, and that `fetch` was called with the parameters you were expecting to call it with.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Using something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock)?

Comment: Yes, that looks like it's designed for the job!

Comment: I wish your comment was given as an answer, so I could accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With unit testing, the idea is to test the unit that you're interested in, and only that.  In this instance, the unit makes use of `fetch`, which itself goes off and talks to websites, so in effect your unit test ends up doing a round trip to a website so you end up "testing" *that* too.  Not what you want in a unit test.

The correct way to test just the part you're interested in is to mock the `fetch` function, and use the mock to verify it is called in the way you expect, plus also return data from the mock to your unit that it can use to complete the test.  You may perform other checks to ensure your unit has processed the return in the way you expected.

It appears that there is at least one [npm package available](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock) for mocking `fetch`.